# Schematron Assert rule embedded in RelaxNG produces undeclared namespace prefix error

Tags: xml, schematron, relaxng

#### Example code

Consider the following somewhat contrived XML instance:

**file.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
  <table aid:trows="3" aid:tcols="2">
    <Cell>header column 1</Cell>
    <Cell>header column 2</Cell>
    <Cell>row 1 column 1</Cell>
    <Cell>row 1 column 2</Cell>
    <Cell>row 2 column 1</Cell>
    <Cell>row 2 column 2</Cell>
  </table>
</section>
```

It successfully validates using the following Relax NG Schema:

**schema.rng**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
  datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
  xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
  xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"
  xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
  <start>
    <ref name="section"/>
  </start>
  <define name="section">
    <element name="section">
      <ref name="table"/>
    </element>
  </define>
  <define name="table">
    <sch:pattern name="Test attributes aid:rows and aid:tcols when multiplied equal count of Cell elements">
      <sch:rule context="table">
        <sch:assert test="count(./Cell) = 6">Count of Cell elements does not match specified @aid:rows and @aid:tcols.</sch:assert>
      </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
    <element name="table">
      <attribute name="aid:trows">
        <data type="integer"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute name="aid:tcols">
        <data type="integer"/>
      </attribute>
      <oneOrMore>
        <element name="Cell">
          <text/>
        </element>
      </oneOrMore>
    </element>
  </define>
</grammar>
```

**Note:** the embedded Schematron rule in `schema.rng`, i.e. the part that reads as follows:

> ```xml
> <sch:pattern name="Test attributes aid:rows and aid:tcols when multiplied equal count of Cell elements">
>  <sch:rule context="table">
>    <sch:assert test="count(./Cell) = 6">Count of Cell elements does not match specified @aid:rows and @aid:tcols.</sch:assert>
>  </sch:rule>
> </sch:pattern>
> ```

This rule `assert`'s that the count of `Cell` element nodes must equal `6`:

#### What am I trying to do?

I'm trying to avoid hard coding what the count of `Cell` elements must be in the XPath `count` function that is currently defined in the Schematron rule. i.e. this part *(shown again below)* stating that the count of `Cell` elements must be six:

```xml
<sch:assert test="count(./Cell) = 6">...</sch:assert>
                                  ^
```

What I want to do is infer what the count of `Cell` elements must be by multiplying the values of the `aid:trows` and `aid:tcols` attributes associated with the `table` element. i.e. infer it from these attributes in *file.xml* shown again below:

```xml
<table aid:trows="3" aid:tcols="2">
                  ^             ^
  ...
</table>
```

#### What have I tried...

I've tried redefining the XPath `count` function in the Schematron rule as follows.

```
<sch:assert test="count(./Cell) = @aid:trows * @aid:tcols">...</sch:assert>
```

However, attempting to validate *file.xml* produces the following error *(btw. I'm using Oxygen XML Editor)*:

> ```
> Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
> Undeclared namespace prefix {aid}
> Got a fatal error trying to create a transformer from the stylesheet!
> ```

There seems to be some issue with the `aid` namespace prefix!

What am I misunderstanding here? How can I fix this?

**What does work?**

To determine whether it's `aid` namespace prefix related I tried the following which does work successfully:

1. In *file.xml* I omitted the `aid` prefix from the `aid:trows` and `aid:tcol` attributes associated with the `table` as shown below:

   ```xml
   ...
   <table trows="3" tcols="2">
       ...
   </table>
   ```
2. Then redefined:

   - the XPath `count` function in the Schematron rule as `count(./Cell) = @trows * @tcols`
   - and defined the attributes for the `table` as `trows` and `tcols`, i.e. omitted the `aid:` prefixes.

   Essentially I redefined the named pattern for `table` to the following:

   ```
   ...
   <define name="table">
     <sch:pattern name="Test attributes aid:rows and aid:tcols when multiplied equal count of Cell elements">
       <sch:rule context="table">
         <!-- change below -->
         <sch:assert test="count(./Cell) = @trows * @tcols">Count of Cell elements does not match specified @aid:rows and @aid:tcols.</sch:assert>
       </sch:rule>
     </sch:pattern>
     <element name="table">
       <!-- change below -->
       <attribute name="trows">
         <data type="integer"/>
       </attribute>
       <!-- change below -->
       <attribute name="tcols">
         <data type="integer"/>
       </attribute>
       <oneOrMore>
         <element name="Cell">
           <text/>
         </element>
       </oneOrMore>
     </element>
   </define>
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. Namespace prefixes used in assert tests in Schemetron must be declared using the Schematron `ns` element. Add the following as the first child within `<grammar>` in the RelaxNG schema:

   `<sch:ns prefix="aid" uri="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"/>`
2. Alternatively, you can assert the namespace of the attributes within the assert test by using the xPath `namespace-uri()` function. Change:

   `@aid:trows`

   to:

   `@*:trows[namespace-uri() = 'http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/']`

   (and the same for `tcols`).
3. Or, if you're lazy, you can use `@*:trows`, which will select `trows` attributes of any namespace.